# Sort python list based on length, and then based on content

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort a list based on element's length, and then based on the contents.
For example, with an input `[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]`, I need to get `[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4],[1,2,3]]`: [1,2,3,4] has the largest elements, and then [2,3,4] is bigger than [1,2,3] in its first element. With an input `[[2,3,5],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]`, `[[2,3,5],[2,3,4],[1,2,3]]` should be returned by comparing element by element when the length of the element is the same.

I could easily sort the list by the length of element, but how can I resort after that?

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
>>> sorted(a, key=len, reverse=True)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't. Sort once.

```
key=lambda a: (-len(a), a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have `key` return a tuple. So in this case:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda item: (len(item), item), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define you own function

```
 def comparing(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
       return len(a) - len(b)
    else:
       return sum(a) - sum(b)
```

Comment: Comparison functions are obsolescent in 2.x and removed from 3.x.